# How to change selected value of dropdown in the powerapps?

Tags: powerapp

I have a checkbox and a dropdown in the powerapps form. The dropdown value will be changed based on the checkbox selection. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Will the dropdown be changeable outside of changing the checkbox?

Comment: In that case, could you use a Calculated column instead of the Dropdown?

Comment: Sorry, client already using dropdown column and its carried data...

Comment: @RajeshSharepointGeek try my answer and let us know if it works..

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, This is quite interesting looks like via Rules these run-time value assignments are disabled at this point. However, there is a workaround

```
Filter(Issues,ID=If(Checkbox1.Value, 6,2))
```

[image]